# How to integrate a highly oscillatory function

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I met a problem when I tried to integrate a function which is a oscillatory function as shown in the following figures. How to prove that it is divergent? [image]

Comment: If it is a function like $\sin(100x)$ , the substitution $t=100x$ helps

Comment: upload the picture directly or write a proper formula, please! also add your own thoughts and attempts